# Clojure fireplace in vim asking for python

Tags: shell, vim, clojure, zsh

Trying to get get fireplace set up in vim but having trouble with some error messages.

When I type `cpr` in a clojure buffer the following error shows up:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>53_RunTests..fireplace#capture_te
st_run..<SNR>53_eval..fireplace#client..fireplace#platform..fireplace#register_
port_file..fireplace#nrepl_connection#open..fireplace#nrepl#for..<SNR>75_nrepl_
process..<SNR>75_nrepl_message..<SNR>75_nrepl_call..<SNR>74_nrepl_transport_cal
l..<SNR>74_nrepl_transport_dispatch:                                           
line    6:                                                                     
E605: Exception not caught: nREPL: zsh:1: command not found: python^@          
Error detected while processing function <SNR>53_RunTests..fireplace#capture_te
st_run..<SNR>53_eval..fireplace#client..fireplace#platform:                    
line    9:                                                                     
E171: Missing :endif
```

The thing I understand is that it cant find python. In my shell I can start python with the `python` command which will fire up 3.4.2.

Im using nixos

:echo has('python') returns 0

echo $PATH and :! echo $PATH return the same path.

What can I try in order to find what is actually causing this error?

Comment: are you on a mac, and if so are you launching vim through some gui fancyness or from the terminal. Next check the path from within vim

Comment: from the looks of it, fireplace is trying to shell out and having an issue; a way around this altogether is to use a version of vim with baked-in python support (depends on where you get it and/or compile it yourself).  use `vim --version` or `:echo has('python')` to check

Comment: fireplace needs a vim with buildin python or starts the system one. in your vim try `:!which python`. i have never used it with system python, so in the end it might just not work as advertised.

Comment: that is the strange thing, zsh cant find python when i try to :! python, so :!which python just returns command not found.

Comment: Where is the system python?  Is the executable (or startup scrip) in the PATH?  It could be that it's not, but that you've got a shell alias defined in your shell config script that allows you to run python from the command line.  Shell aliases wouldn't necessarily be exported to the shell that's run by `!` in vim, and definitely wouldn't be available if vim starts python directly without running a shell.

Comment: Another thought that might be relevant: I gather that you use zsh.  Is vim using zsh when you shell out of it?  Maybe it's using bash, for example.  Then what you set in your zsh config wouldn't necessarily be available to bash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install/compile vim with python support for vim-fireplace to work, and this may not be the default on your system. I believe typing `:help python` will do this for you. If you don't get anything, you may have to recompile vim with python support, for which I'll direct you towards Google for now.

Another option if you have pip installed is to consider switching to neovim. Installing neovim with `pip install neovim` will get you python support. I've been using neovim lately, and it's worked pretty well for me.